# How to backup a mixed-mode CD with MP3 for the Audio Tracks?

Tags: audio, backup, mp3

I'm currently in the process a tidying up my CDs, among which there are some PC games with mixed-mode CDs, i.e. they have a data track plus some audio tracks (usually the game's music). In order to save some space, I'd like to have the audio tracks as MP3s, yet still be able to mount the CD image. What tools can achieve this?

Comment: so, what do you want the software to do?

Comment: @NabilAziz back up the CD including its audio trasks in MP3 and mounting it as a virtual CD later on which appears to still have conventional audio tracks. Or put differently, a CD image with lossy audio track compression. Or at least FLAC...

Comment: And the game should be able to play the audio content? I think that's quite impossible without rewriting said game.

Comment: @mtak That's I want the sought tool to simply mount that CD as virtual CD, something like Daemon Tools but with this MP3-as-audiotrack support